# How to keep border primaryColor

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to set up `TextFormField` on Flutter.

When focus on `TextFormField`, it turns primaryColor.
However I would like to keep border and titles primaryColor whenever they are not focused on. 
I don't expect any color change on border and titles.

How can I write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will stop the border color from changing. Add a `InputDecoration` to the `TextFormField`:

```
TextFormField(
....
decoration: InputDecoration(
  border: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: //put your color, width: //if you want to change the width)),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wrap your TextField() in a new Theme as shown below, because the TextField is using the default theme setup in main.dart.

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.redAccent,
  ),
  child: TextField(
  )
);
```